# Am I using Python's For loop incorrectly? How can I solve this?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am attempting to use the following script in twilio to create a chatbot.
However if the message sent to the chatbot contains keywords from the CChangDict then it works fine. If the message contains words from the SLoansDict then it prompts an error 5000. This I believe is down the my incorrect useage of the "for" loop.

Any ideas on how I can improve my code to make sure that if a message contains words from either dictionary ( CChangeDict or SLoansDict ) that the correct answer is sent in response?

Thanks!

```
    def respond(message):
    response = MessagingResponse()
    response.message(message)
    return str(response)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    student = request.form.get('From')
    message = request.form.get('Body').lower()

    for keyword in CChangeDict:
        if keyword in message:
            return respond(JoeDict["ClimateChange"])

    for keywork in SLoansDict:
        if keyword in message:
            return respond(JoeDict["StudentLoans"])
```

Comment: `keywork` needs to be `keyword` spelling check there. but to your point, you have not shown the two respective  dictionaries (how have you set those up), you could also check both dictionaries, instead of doing it separately using *zip*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the second `for` loop – `keywork` should be `keyword`.

You're getting error 500 because you aren't responding *anything* in the case where the keyword isn't found.

All in all,

```
for keyword in CChangeDict:
    if keyword in message:
        return respond(JoeDict["ClimateChange"])

for keyword in SLoansDict:
    if keyword in message:
        return respond(JoeDict["StudentLoans"])

return respond("I don't know what to say.")
```

or to coalesce the two for loops,

```
for keywords, response in (
    (CChangeDict, JoeDict["ClimateChange"]),
    (SLoansDict, JoeDict["StudentLoans"]),
):
    if any(keyword in message for keyword in keywords):
        return respond(response)

return respond("I don't know what to say.")
```